# Laravel how I can undispatch a delayed dispatched job?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

In my laravel code I dispatched a job:

```
 MyJob::dispatch()->delay(now()->addHours(48));
```

But on an another piece of code I want this job to be undispatched because conditions are found that no longer job's needed to run. The phpcode for meeting the undispatch criteria is:

```
if ( $no_job_needed){
 // Undispatch Job there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatchIf method like:

```
MyJob::dispatchIf($no_job_needed  === false)->delay(now()->addHours(48));
```

Comment: Well my case is that I dispatch a job for example for allocating some points to a user. But an another event eg an received api call causes the condition for my job to be no longer needed.